# Handling H264 encoded RTP video stream with Libjitsi Library in Swing - how to render stream?

Tags: java, swing, networking, video-streaming, rtp

I am using the Java library at https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi .

I want to stream H264 video (in this case the video is a desktop/screen stream) over RTP and then render it. I can figure out how to stream it, but not how to render the stream. Given the following code (fully compilable and runnable with the Libjitsi Jars and native libraries), what do I do next to render the video stream into a Swing JFrame or JPanel? Apparently there is some sort of JMF JAWTRenderer or maybe I can use Java Media Framework (JMF), Freedom for Media in Java (FMJ), JavaFX in Swing embedding, or VLC media player Swing embedding with the VLCj library. What is the best (easiest, good performance, bug free, non-deprecated) way to render this RTP video stream into a Java Swing application?

Also, at the very bottom, I have a few more related questions.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.DefaultStreamConnector;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaDirection;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaService;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaStream;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaStreamTarget;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaType;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.MediaUseCase;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.StreamConnector;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.device.MediaDevice;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.format.MediaFormat;

/**
 * This class streams screen recorded video. It can either send an H264 encoded
 * RTP stream or receive one depending on the value of the variable
 * isReceivingVideo_.
 */
public class VideoStreamer {

    // Set to false if sending video, set to true if receiving video.
    private static final boolean isReceivingVideo_ = true;

    public final MediaService mediaService_;
    private final Map<MediaFormat, Byte> RTP_payload_number_map_;

    public static final int LOCAL_BASE_PORT_NUMBER = 15000;
    public static final String REMOTE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
    public static final int REMOTE_BASE_PORT_NUMBER = 10000;

    private MediaStream videoMediaStream_;
    private final int localBasePort_;
    private final InetAddress remoteAddress_;
    private final int remoteBasePort_;

    /**
     * Initializes a new VideoStreamer instance which is to send or receive
     * video from a specific host and a specific port.
     *
     * @param isReceiver - true if this instance of VideoStreamer is receiving a
     * video stream, false if it is sending a video stream.
     */
    public VideoStreamer(boolean isReceiver) throws IOException {
        this.remoteAddress_ = InetAddress.getByName(REMOTE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS);
        mediaService_ = LibJitsi.getMediaService();
        RTP_payload_number_map_ = mediaService_.getDynamicPayloadTypePreferences();
        if (isReceiver) {
            this.localBasePort_ = LOCAL_BASE_PORT_NUMBER;
            this.remoteBasePort_ = REMOTE_BASE_PORT_NUMBER;
            startVideoStream(MediaDirection.RECVONLY);
        } else {
            // switch the local and remote ports for the transmitter so they hook up with the receiver.
            this.localBasePort_ = REMOTE_BASE_PORT_NUMBER;
            this.remoteBasePort_ = LOCAL_BASE_PORT_NUMBER;
            startVideoStream(MediaDirection.SENDONLY);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the receipt of video, starts it, and tries to record any
     * incoming packets.
     *
     * @param intended_direction either sending or receiving an RTP video
     * stream.
     */
    public final void startVideoStream(final MediaDirection intended_direction) throws SocketException {
        final MediaType video_media_type = MediaType.VIDEO;
        final int local_video_port = localBasePort_;
        final int remote_video_port = remoteBasePort_;
        MediaDevice video_media_device = mediaService_.getDefaultDevice(video_media_type, MediaUseCase.DESKTOP);
        final MediaStream video_media_stream = mediaService_.createMediaStream(video_media_device);
        video_media_stream.setDirection(intended_direction);
        // Obtain the list of formats that are available for a specific video_media_device and pick H264 if availible.
        MediaFormat video_format = null;
        final List<MediaFormat> supported_video_formats = video_media_device.getSupportedFormats();
        for (final MediaFormat availible_video_format : supported_video_formats) {
            final String encoding = availible_video_format.getEncoding();
            final double clock_rate = availible_video_format.getClockRate();
            if (encoding.equals("H264") && clock_rate == 90000) {
                video_format = availible_video_format;
            }
        }
        if (video_format == null) {
            System.out.println("You do not have the H264 video codec");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        final byte dynamic_RTP_payload_type_for_H264 = getRTPDynamicPayloadType(video_format);
        if (dynamic_RTP_payload_type_for_H264 < 96 || dynamic_RTP_payload_type_for_H264 > 127) {
            System.out.println("Invalid RTP payload type number");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        video_media_stream.addDynamicRTPPayloadType(dynamic_RTP_payload_type_for_H264, video_format);
        video_media_stream.setFormat(video_format);
        final int local_RTP_video_port = local_video_port + 0;
        final int local_RTCP_video_port = local_video_port + 1;
        final StreamConnector video_connector = new DefaultStreamConnector(
                new DatagramSocket(local_RTP_video_port),
                new DatagramSocket(local_RTCP_video_port)
        );
        video_media_stream.setConnector(video_connector);
        final int remote_RTP_video_port = remote_video_port + 0;
        final int remote_RTCP_video_port = remote_video_port + 1;
        video_media_stream.setTarget(new MediaStreamTarget(
                new InetSocketAddress(remoteAddress_, remote_RTP_video_port),
                new InetSocketAddress(remoteAddress_, remote_RTCP_video_port))
        );
        video_media_stream.setName(video_media_type.toString());
        this.videoMediaStream_ = video_media_stream;
        videoMediaStream_.start();
        listenForVideoPackets(video_connector.getDataSocket());
    }

    public void listenForVideoPackets(final DatagramSocket videoDataSocket) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean socket_is_closed = false;
                while (!socket_is_closed) {
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
                    final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    try {
                        videoDataSocket.receive(packet);
                        final byte[] packet_data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
                        System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet_data, 0, packet.getLength());
                        final StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < ((packet_data.length > 30) ? 30 : packet_data.length); ++i) {
                            byte b = packet_data[i];
                            string_builder.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                        }
                        System.out.println("First thirty (or fewer) bytes of packet in hex: " + string_builder.toString());
                    } catch (SocketException socket_closed) {
                        System.out.println("Socket is closed");
                        socket_is_closed = true;
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the given format exists in the list of formats with listed
     * dynamic RTP payload numbers and returns that number.
     *
     * @param format - format to look up an RTP payload number for
     * @return - RTP payload on success or -1 either if payload number cannot be
     * found or if payload number is static.
     */
    public byte getRTPDynamicPayloadType(final MediaFormat format) {
        for (Map.Entry<MediaFormat, Byte> entry : RTP_payload_number_map_.entrySet()) {
            final MediaFormat map_format = (MediaFormat) entry.getKey();
            final Byte rtp_payload_type = (Byte) entry.getValue();
            if (map_format.getClockRate() == format.getClockRate() && map_format.getEncoding().equals(format.getEncoding())) {
                return rtp_payload_type;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Close the MediaStream.
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            this.videoMediaStream_.stop();
        } finally {
            this.videoMediaStream_.close();
            this.videoMediaStream_ = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LibJitsi.start();
        try {
            VideoStreamer rtp_streamer
                    = new VideoStreamer(isReceivingVideo_);
            try {
                /*
                 * Wait for the media to be received and (hopefully) played back.
                 * Transmits for 1 minute and receives for 30 seconds to allow the
                 * tranmission to have a delay (if necessary).
                 */
                final long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
                final long waiting_period;
                if (isReceivingVideo_) {
                    waiting_period = 30000;
                } else {
                    waiting_period = 60000;
                }
                try {
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - then < waiting_period) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            } finally {
                rtp_streamer.close();
            }
            System.err.println("Exiting VideoStreamer");
        } finally {
            LibJitsi.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code by first linking the Libjitsi jar files (by listing them under "Libraries") and specifying the location of native (.so, .dll) libraries via "-Djava.library.path=/path/to/native/libraries", I first run it with final boolean isReceivingVideo = true, and then I run another instance with final boolean isReceivingVideo = false and then the two instances of this application stream to each other. In addition, I have a function, public void listenForVideoPackets, that prints out the first 30 bytes of each packet in hexadecimal format. When I run it, I get the following hexadecimal byte values:

[image: Hex values for RTP byte array stream]

I am just an undergraduate student, so my networking knowledge is limited. Can someone explain what do all these hex patterns mean? Why is the fourth byte of the RTP packet always increasing (33, 35, 37, 39, etc.)? Why is the first packet only 16 bytes while all the other packets are much longer? What does the first packet mean? Why are the first 12 or so bytes identical across all the packets, except for the fourth byte, which is always increasing? What do these numbers mean and how do I handle this RTP stream?

Answer (score 1):

I found a folder called "PacketPlayer" in one person's Libjitsi examples folder (not the one that comes with the library). Their git might contain some useful hints... https://github.com/Metaswitch/libjitsi/tree/master/src/org/jitsi/examples/PacketPlayer

Note that there is a "VideoContainer" class that may be useful. See https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi/blob/master/src/org/jitsi/util/swing/VideoContainer.java

Also, the first 12 bytes are the RTP header. Using the header diagram at http://www.siptutorial.net/RTP/header.html and the fact that RTP payload type in the above code is 99, the RTP header above breaks down into something like:

RTP version: 2, padding: 0, extension: 0, CSRC count: 0, [first byte]

marker: 0, payload type: 99, [second byte]

sequence number: -11221 [3rd, 4th byte]

timestamp: 1082411848

SSRC source: -504863636

Oddly enough, the sequence number is definitely NOT increasing by 1 as it should. It is increasing by 2. This might mean that your datagram socket is getting every other packet rather than every packet.